# Android: How to get the handle of WebViews that are created programmatically to reload them (while they have no ids)

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created an applications that has (X) number of tabs each tab is created dynamically  and an associated WebView is created for it.

I have also a Menu that has a "Reload" button I want to reload all the dynamically created webviews upon a click of this menu, my problem is how to get the handle of these WebViews that has no ID.

Here is a snippet of the Activity that creates the WebViews.

// Please Notice that in the code below the 2 Strings `@myId` and `@url` are passed from another activity.

```
WebView browse;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Activity activity = this;     

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        browse=new WebView(this);
        browse.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN );        
        setContentView(browse);
        Intent sender=getIntent();
        String myUrl = sender.getStringExtra("url");
        int myId = Integer.parseInt( sender.getStringExtra("webid") );      
        browse.setId( myId );
        browse.setWebViewClient( new Youm7WebViewClient());
        browse.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
        browse.loadUrl( myUrl );

    }
```

now in the other activity I tried to do the following upon a click of the "Reload" button

*Please notice that `i` is the same value sent in the activity above `MyId`*

```
// this crashes the app
for(int i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
     String X = String.valueOf(i);
     WebView ourWebview = (WebView) findViewById(i);
     ourWebview.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are not re-using the WebView reference named 'browse' then you can just call `browse.reload();` If however you are re-using that reference (i.e. you make another new WebView and set the same browse equal to the new one.) then you could keep an ArrayList or some other data structure to hold your WebView references. Then you could loop through it and call .reload() on each objects index.

Comment: and How do I call that from another activity ?

Comment: Your are trying to refresh the WebViews from an Activity that is not showing them?

Comment: I have an activity that Creates Menu Items, Handle Clicks on Menu Items, Create Tabs, Each adds and Intent and Each intent creates a WebView with a URL relative to the Tab associated.

Comment: Activity 1: the Main Activity Creates Various UI items including Tabs , Each tab is associated with an Intent this intent creates a webviews through another Activity 

2: activity 2 is driven by an intent called from Activity 1 and it creates the Webview.

Comment: One solution could be make a barebones activity that holds your data structure with WebViews, then extend that activity with the others. That way all of them will have access to your WebView references.

Comment: I have now created an Array of Intents in Activity 1,  can I get the Webview by Accessing Children of that Intent ? ?

Comment: No, you need an array of WebViews. and add them to your arraylist right after you create them with new WebView(this);